# Setting up an equation of a line given a coordinate and a graph that the line touches

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Say you are given the graph $f(x)=x^2$

You are also given a point $p$, for this example take $p=(-1, -1)$

How do i set up an equation of a line that passes trough $p$, and touches the graph $f(x)=x^2$ somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: By "touches", do you mean that it is a tangent?

Comment: ConMan yeah thats what i meant sorry should have clarified

Comment: @RichardBatsbak good news, you can [edit] your post to include that clarification. Please do so when you get a chance!

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a line of gradient $m$ through the point $(-1,-1)$ is $y+1=m(x+1)$. Substitute this into $y=x^2$ to get a quadratic in $x$, if the discriminant of this quadratic is zero then the line will touch the curve.

> $x^2-mx+(1-m)=0$

so

> $\Delta=m^2-4(1-m)=0$

so

> $m=-2 \pm 2 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So it's not even certain that my question has an answer? Because what you said is checking if there is en answer or not? Is that correct?

Comment: Could you explain further how you get the first equation: x^2 - mx + (1 - M) = 0

Comment: Eliminate $y$ from $y=x^2$ and $y+1=m(x+1)$.

Comment: Thanks, Donald!

Comment: Cool ! You are welcome $\ddot \smile$

Comment: If the given point is "outside" the parabola (so for y=x^2, below the curve) then there should be 2 possible tangents you can draw. If it's "inside", then there will be no solutions.